# Is there any specific order in the creation queries of pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Postgres dumps created on the same database are sometimes different in the order of creation . Do we have any specific order in the creation of tables when creating a postgres dump.

I use the command : pg_dump -U (user name) -h localhost -d (DB name) -s > file.sql

Comment: There is a topological sort of the sections of the dump. Within the sections there is no guaranteed order (probably the order  of the objects  inside the catalogs, or the OIDs) BTW: you could check the source...